# Input 1k datas using CSV file from kobocollect UI / endpoint

Tags: android, appium, kobo, kobotoolbox

I’m newbie to using kobocollect.

I need support to create automation for input 1k data via kobocollect UI.
I’ve tried to download kobocollect.apk from playstore using https://apkcombo.com/, but somehow I can’t inspect the element using appium inspector.

Do you have any advice if I can’t inspect UI element of kobocollect.apk, which endpoint that I can use to input 1k of data using CSV files?

I wish I can input bulk data using UI / endpoint of kobocollect and the create automation UI to do UI validation from client side.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.